# Page load order problematic - styles not applying

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, json, jquery-mobile

I am building a simple web app for mobile platforms using jQuery Mobile and in that, I intend to read some data from an API sending it as JSON (which I have exposed from a server side Django based project),  and then parses it using jQuery's mechanism and then I create list elements based off that data.
Now, I have the following index.html:

```
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Playism App</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jm/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jsonParser.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/major.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jm/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jm/jquery.mobile.theme-1.3.2.min.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>List of games: </p><br/>
        <div id="gameContainer" data-role="page">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" id="gamesList">
                <!-- Content here will be dynamically generated based on the JSON output parsed from the API feed -->   
                <li><a href="#">Dummy</a></li>
            </ul>       
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/gamesRenderer.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){ 
                renderGames();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, just to test I created that Dummy list element and it's rendering perfect but there is no styling applied to any of the new elements which I inject using .append() calls from jQuery. The code is as follows:

```
function renderGames(){
    for (var i = objCreated.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        $("ul#gamesList").append("<li><a href='#''>" + objCreated[i].name + "</a></li></ul>");

    };
}
```

and as can be seen in index.html, I am calling it at DOM ready but no jQuery mobile styling gets applied to these manually injected list elements whereas the Dummy element gets proper styling. I believe something is wrong with the order in which the elements are called. 
Thanks in advance !

Comment: In render game function, after you finish adding items, call enhancement `$('#gamelist').listview('refresh')`. And don't use `.ready()` in JQM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't get me wrong but this question was asked so many times, but here's a solution for you:

```
function renderGames(){
    for (var i = objCreated.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        $("ul#gamesList").append("<li><a href='#''>" + objCreated[i].name + "</a></li></ul>");

    };
    $("ul#gamesList").listview('refresh');
}
```

You need to use:

```
$("ul#gamesList").listview('refresh');
```

When working with a dynamically added jQuery Mobile you must manually start markup enhancement process. Read more about it in this **[article](http://www.gajotres.net/jquery-mobile-and-how-to-enhance-the-markup-of-dynamically-added-content/)**.

One other thing, never use document ready with jQuery Mobile, they should not be combined. Read more about it **[here](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/)**. Sometimes it works sometimes not. Basically when working with jQuery Mobile always use page events.

Your final javascript should look like this:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#gameContainer', function(){ 
    renderGames();
});

function renderGames(){
    for (var i = 10 - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        $("ul#gamesList").append("<li><a href='#''>Some object" + i + "</a></li></ul>");

    };
    $("ul#gamesList").listview('refresh');
}
```

Working example: [**http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/5uPfM/**](http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/5uPfM/)

Answer (score 0):

Seems the for loop make the css cannot load properly. Don't know what is the 'objCreated'.

Try to migrate the code here in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joydesigner/zK79n/).
Here is the code:

```
<body>
    <p>List of games: </p><br/>
    <div id="gameContainer" data-role="page">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" id="gamesList">

            <li><a href="#">Dummy</a></li>
        </ul>       
    </div>


</body>

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    renderGames();
});

function renderGames(){

   $("ul#gamesList").append("<li><a href='#''>Hello world!</a></li></ul>")

}
```

The css seems works on the injected elements. The list-style is "none" because of the jQuery Mobile UI css works.

Comment: That's exactly the problem...
Please see the screenshot here:
http://s14.postimg.org/dtv7ggtnl/Edit_fiddle_JSFiddle.png

I want Hello world to be styled the same as Dummy...

Comment: Got fixed... Found a similar thread elsewhere:

This is the solution:
$("#gamesList").listview('refresh');

Answer (score -1):

**first apply css** and see your **css** file are linked properly

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/major.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jm/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jm/jquery.mobile.theme-1.3.2.min.css">
```

**then JS** and see your **js** file are linked properly

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jm/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jsonParser.js"></script>
```

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
            renderGames();
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: The files are linked and loading properly. Just that styles are not being applied on dynamically injected ones e.g.:

http://s14.postimg.org/dtv7ggtnl/Edit_fiddle_JSFiddle.png

Comment: see the jsfiddle. The injected the element is styled. http://jsfiddle.net/joydesigner/zK79n/

Comment: You call that styled?